# Presigned-URL"The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method." with Swift

Tags: swift, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload a file to a presigned URL. I am getting a "SignatureDoesNotMatch" error.

```swift
func uploadFile(to url: URL, fileURL: URL) {
        print("uploadFile() called with upload URL: \(url) and file URL: \(fileURL)")
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "PUT"
        request.cachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
        request.setValue("audio/m4a", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        
        logRequestDetails(request)  // Log request details

        let task = URLSession.shared.uploadTask(with: request, fromFile: fileURL) { data, response, error in
            if let error = error {
                // Log detailed error information
                print("Error uploading file: \(error)")
                return
            }

            if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                print("Upload response status code: \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
                if httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {
                    print("File uploaded successfully.")
                } else {
                    print("Upload failed with status code: \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
                    // Log response body if available
                    if let data = data, let responseBody = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                        print("Response body: \(responseBody)")
                    }
                }
            } else {
                print("Failed to get HTTP response. Response: \(String(describing: response))")
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

Things that have been checked:

- Is the URL actually functioning?
  Yes. I can upload using it if I use curl like this:
  curl -v -X PUT --upload-file test.txt https://...
- Does the file exist?
  Yes.
- Is this timing out?
  Absolutely not, this is a 5kB file, it has 60 seconds to upload.
- What's the error exactly?

> `SignatureDoesNotMatch`The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.ASIARJSVSHXJ267....PUT